# SCSS relative value in @mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I want to make a short-written `flex` rules using classes in SCSS. I want to write a one time `justify-content` class block and to use `@mixin` in order to insert it to the flex options.

How (if possible) can I write a relative variable inside the `@mixin` that will represents the parent class that the `@mixin` was included in?

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  @include justification;
}

.column {
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  @include justification;
}

@mixin justification {
  &-center {
    @extend {parent};
    justify-content: center;
  }
  &-start {
    @extend {parent};
    justify-content: start;
  }
}
```

What comes instead of {parent}, where 'parent' represents the class where this mixin was included in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! I did it!

The key to the answer is to pass the includer's class name to the `@mixin` as an argument. Like so:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  @include justification(&);
}

.column {
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  @include justification(&);
}

@mixin justification($class) {
  &-center {
    @extend #{$class};
    justify-content: center;
  }
  &-start {
    @extend #{$class};
    justify-content: start;
  }
}
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a mixin as shown below and give default values in it.

```
@mixin flex-properties($flex:flex, $justify-content: center, $align-items: center) {
  display: $flex;
  justify-content: $justify-content;
  align-items: $align-items;
}
```

To use the above mixin & also you can change the default value of its parameters:-

```
.some-class {
  @include flex-properties(flex, space-between, center);
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, wanted something more specific